# storing time to a db and comparing with current time

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple question, that just needs verification, it's about how time is stored in mysql, here is how i store it:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
$u_id=$_SESSION['user'];
//insert current time to db, i set the type of time to TIME 
$query="INSERT INTO time(id,u_id,time) VALUES('NULL','".$u_id."',CURTIME())";
mysql_query($query);
}
```

that is how i store it, now i would also need to compare it to a value, later on:

```
 //set current time
$curr_time=time();
//set maximum time to 5min
$max=300; 
//get previous time from db
$query="SELECT * FROM time";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$prev_time=$row['time'];
//get difference in time
$diff=$curr_time-$prev_time;
//if max time is surpassed
if($diff>$max)
{
  echo "maximum time surpassed!";

    }
```

that's the simple code, first of all, is the syntax for inserting the time to the table okay(the CURTIME() thing), also is the comparison fine, will the result stored in $diff yield seconds?thank you, and sorry if you think this question is a waste of time.

Comment: You could use timestamps (seconds from Epoch) to easily do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CURTIME()` will only give you the time, you likely want `NOW()` which is the date and time.  Then you will need to use `strtotime` to convert the saved value from the database to seconds since epoch.

Comment: thanks,will do so, and i only need the time for what i'm doing, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your query:

```
 $query = "SELECT id FROM time WHERE time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTES > NOW()";
```

is there are no results, time has passed.

MySQL has terrific time and date handling functions. Use them.

(I'd also add some extra parts in the `WHERE` clause, if you have more than one record, you'll be looking at the wrong one probably.)

Answer (score 0):

Since CURTIME is only on a daily basis and I suspect you want your function to cover the span over days I'd suggest you use NOW() instead as it gives you this format instead:

2012-11-06 09:39:34

Answer (score 0):

```
 also is the comparison fine, will the result stored in $diff yield seconds?
```

You can't directly compare mysql CURTIME() with  time() function in PHP.

For example:

In MySql:

[CURTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) will return only time.

```
select CURTIME();
+-----------+
| CURTIME() |
+-----------+
| 14:15:11  |
+-----------+
```

In PHP

[time()](https://www.php.net/time) will return current Unix timestamp.

```
echo time();
1352191547
```

Look at sberry's answer for compassion.